# Export Symbolised Point Feature to Text File in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, export, xml

Is there a way to save symbols of a feature class from Arc Map as XML or text file format? I know one can set up representations on a feature class in a Geoodatabase and Export XML Workspace, but I thought there was an easier way to do this..

Comment: You can save your layer from ArcMap as a Layer File (.lyr) which includes symbology.  I'm not sure though what you mean by 'text file format' or how you'd store a symbol in a text file?